# Using dictionary to sum rows with same key

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a data sheet of numbers with an impact table

```
 A1    1
 A1    5
 A1    6
 B1    2
 B1    3
 C1    6
 C1    8
```

The result I would like

```
A1    1              A1    12
A1    5              B1    5
A1    6              C1    14
B1    2
B1    3
C1    6
C1    8
```

I thought I could use a dictionary. I have been researching for a week and nothing I could understand is showing.

I wrote this bit of code:

```
Dim k As String
Dim d As Object
For each k in d.keys
    lastRow=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x=2 to lastRow
        If Cells(x,"A")=k Then
        'basically sum column B and print key + total
        End If
    Next x
```

Comment: Why not just use a Pivot Table?

Comment: I felt fancy. you are right worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary is a quick way, especially if you load data into array first.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    arr = [A1:B7].Value
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
    Next

    [C1].Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.KEYS)
    [D1].Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)

End Sub
```